# django StreamingHttpResponse - catch exception raised in streaming_content iterator

Tags: python, django, iterator, django-views, chunked

I'm trying to handle errors while returning a `StreamingHttpResponse`:

The exception raised manually inside the iterator used as `straeming_content` is not caught.

here's the code:

```
def reportgen_iterator(request, object_id):
    output_format = request.GET.get('output', 'pdf')
    debug_mode = request.GET.get('debug', False)
    response_data = {
        'progress': 'Retrieving data...',
    }
    # code....
    yield json.dumps(response_data)

    # code ...
    raise Exception('bla bla') # manually raised exception

    # other code ......
    yield json.dumps(response_data)



class StreamingView(View):
    def get(self, request, object_id):
        """
        """
        stream = reportgen_iterator(request, object_id)
        try:
            response = StreamingHttpResponse(
                streaming_content=stream, status=200,
                content_type='application/octet-stream'
            )
            response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            # exception not catched
            return HttpResponseServerError(e.message)
```

any help about how correctly handle this? The `except` clause is never reached.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have returned from the `get` method long before the exception in `reportgen_iterator` has been raised.

Why is that?

> It should be given an iterator that yields strings as content. You
>   cannot access its content, except by iterating the response object
>   itself. This should only occur when the response is returned to the
>   client.

The view function returns with the iterator (in your case the generator) but that isn't iterated fully while you are still inside the function. That's why the exception is never caught in the `get` method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects